# Keras & Pytorch Conv2D give different results with same weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
import torch, torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np

# Define the PyTorch layer
pt_layer = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 12, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)

# Get the weight tensor from the PyTorch layer
pt_weights = pt_layer.weight.detach().numpy()

# Create the equivalent Keras layer
keras_layer = Conv2D(12, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(None, None, 3))

# Build the Keras layer to initialize its weights
keras_layer.build((None, None, None, 3))

# Transpose the PyTorch weights to match the expected shape of the Keras layer
keras_weights = pt_weights.transpose(2, 3, 1, 0)

# Set the weights of the Keras layer to the PyTorch weights
keras_layer.set_weights([keras_weights])

#Test both models
arr = np.random.normal(0,1,(1, 3, 224, 224))

print(pt_layer(torch.from_numpy(arr).float())[0,0])
print(keras_layer(arr.transpose(0,2,3,1))[0,:,:,0])
```

I would expect both prints to be quite similar, but the are really different. I ran it on a Colab to make sure it wasn't due to old Pytorch/Keras versions. I'm sure I missed something trivial, bu I can't find it...
Any help would be welcome, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: The padding in Keras and Pytorch are quite different it seems. To fix, use ZeroPadding2D instead:

```
keras_layer = tf.keras.Sequential([
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)),
    Conv2D(12, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', use_bias=False, input_shape=(None, None, 3))
])
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above: for those curious, it has to do with how padding is calculated with respect to image size. The height of the output image is calculated as

`output height = (input height + padding height top + padding height bottom - kernel height) / (stride height) + 1`

Same for the width.
Thus, for an image of size 5, kernel of size 3, and stride of 2, we get

`output height = (5 + 1 + 1 - 3) / 2 + 1 = 3`

which is an integer. When the output is not an integer, PyTorch and Keras behave differently. For instance, in the example above, the target image size will be 122.5, which will be rounded down to 122.

PyTorch, regardless of rounding, will always add padding on all sides (due to the layer definition). Keras, on the other hand, will not add padding at the top and left of the image, resulting in the convolution starting at the original top left of the image, and not the padded one, giving a different result.

Schematically, if we have an a 4x4 image, it looks like so: (where xs indicate the convolution, 0s are padding, and dots are "missing" padding):

```
PyTorch       Keras
xxx000        ......
xxx110        .xxx10
xxx110        .xxx10
011110        .xxx10
011110        .11110
000000        .00000
```